# Move the check mark in MacOS dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, macos

I made a drop down list using the `<select>` and `<option>` tag, where every time a  new input is typed, the program creates a new option tag with value attribute to add it to the existing options in the drop down list.

However, my client uses a MacOS and he wanted to move the check mark on the drop down list to the recently added option. The check mark only moves when you click on the selected line, but in my case, I want it to also move to the recently added/typed data.

**Here is the HTML code:**

```
<!-- Created select tag so user can access history of talk -->
<div style="top:60px;position:absolute;z-index:2" id="speechBox">
    <!-- The select tag acts like a drop down button, so it passes its value to the input box and not to itself -->
    <select id = 'combo-box' title = "Saved Talk" onchange="document.getElementById('userText').value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].text; document.getElementById('idValue').value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
  </select>
    <span class = "dropdown" name = "Saved Talk"></span>
    <input id ="userText" name="userText" type="text" onfocus="this.select()" ></input>
    <input name="idValue" id="idValue" type="hidden">
    <button id="speakText" class="toolbutton" title="Speak"></button>
  <hr>
</div>
```

**And the JS:**

```
hiddenArray(); // Access speakArray

// Function containing the speakArray, which saves the recent talk array
function hiddenArray() {
    speakArray = [];
}

function playVoice(language, text) {
  playing = text;

        //Adds option when text is spoken
        var addUserInput = document.createElement("OPTION");
        addUserInput.setAttribute("value", playing);
        addUserInput.text = playing;
        document.getElementById("combo-box").appendChild(addUserInput);

        speakArray.push(playing); // Adds recent talks to speakArray

  if(document.getElementById('mode').innerHTML=="2"){
    //After the voice is loaded, playSound callback is called
    getBotReply(text);
    setTimeout(function(){
        loadVoice(language, playSound);
    }, 4000);
  }
  else{
            loadVoice(language, playSound);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out in the end. Here is the code:

```
 hiddenArray(); // Access speakArray

// Function containing the speakArray, which saves the recent talk array
function hiddenArray() {
    speakArray = [];
}

function playVoice(language, text) {
  playing = text;

  //Adds option when text is spoken
  var addUserInput = document.createElement("OPTION");
  addUserInput.setAttribute("value", playing);
  addUserInput.text = playing;
  document.getElementById("combo-box").appendChild(addUserInput);

  document.getElementById("combo-box").value = playing;

  speakArray.push(playing); // Adds recent talks to speakArray

  if(document.getElementById('mode').innerHTML=="2"){
    //After the voice is loaded, playSound callback is called
    getBotReply(text);
    setTimeout(function(){
        loadVoice(language, playSound);
    }, 4000);
  }
  else{
            loadVoice(language, playSound);
  }
}
```

So what I did here is asign the value of the combo box (select tag) to the recently added option (variable playing).